# Confusing random generator code

Tags: java, random

[In this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html#implementation), why does it say...

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt();
```

What is the second line doing? Why is it there?

I'm thinking it might "freshen" the Random variable, something to do with the seed or something? I have no idea...

Comment: call nextInt() method of random class

Comment: Yeah but it isnt assigned to a variable.

Comment: must be a mistake, i think

Comment: Would that call to nextInt() advance the random numbers anyway?  I.e., if the first call returns 2 and the second returns 4, would you call nextInt() to avoid getting the 2 and skip straight to using the 4s?

Comment: @BrianJ - When you initialize an instance of `Random` without a seed, it takes some "unlikely to be reused value" (in some cases this has been current clock time, which isn't terribly secure...).  Which means that, at _compile_ time, you have no clue what number it's going to "skip" (keep in mind that the second call can still generate the same integer value as this first one, although that's unlikely).  It's worthless for any purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the creator doesn't store that value generated anywhere, it does not serve any purpose. In which case it could just be a mistake. The code works whether that line is included or not since it does not contribute anything.

Answer (score 0):

The line `random.nextInt()` without actually storing the return value is calculating a new 32-Bit random value without actually using it, which is pretty useless. The program's behavior will not change significantly if you remove that line.